# Get readings from 2 different devices which transmits different number of samples/sec Rpi python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have 2 devices. One laser distance measurement device which transmits samples via serial at 20Hz, and one IMU which transmits several samples by the time the laser transmits one. The problem is that python will hold at readline for device 1 until it gets a reading, while in the meantime i could get several readings from the IMU.
This is the code i have so far:

```
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import datetime
import time
import serial

# Device 1, Laser
ser1=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',115200, timeout=0.1)

# Device 2, IMU
ser2=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1',115200, timeout=0.1)

# Create file
starttime = datetime.now()                        
filename = starttime.strftime("measurement/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.dat")
header = "Time[s]\tDistance[cm]\n"
f = open(filename, 'w+')
f.write(header)

while True:

    # Get reading from laser
    reading = ser1.readline()
    now = datetime.now()
    t = (now - starttime).total_seconds()

    # Get reading from IMU
    reading2 = ser1.readline()
    now = datetime.now()
    t2 = (now - starttime).total_seconds()    

    # Append data to .dat file
    f = open(filename, 'a+')
    f.write(str(t)+'\t'+str(reading)+'\n') # Not saving readings from IMU in this example
    print(str(t)+'\t'+str(reading))

f.close()
```

I want get as many readings as possible from the IMU in the time the laser has a new reading. The IMU is clock customizable, but not the laser. I have thought about implementing asyncio for handling the readings. Does anyone have experience with asyncio? How can i make sure that no readings get ignored? I also have to make a common time axis for all readings. Do you have any suggestions? Communication with I2C is also a possibility.